# Is there any way to use the same es6 module import paths for Node and browsers without bundling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I've been playing around with using es6 modules directly, without using Webpack, rollup, etc. After reading [this article](https://salomvary.com/es6-modules-in-browsers.html), I settled on the following:

```
import { MyObject } from './node_modules/module_name/index.mjs'
```

This works fairly well (in both browsers, and node using the esm module and running with node -r esm), but falls apart if you have nested dependencies. For example, if you have two modules that both depend on the same version of a third module, npm will only install a single copy of the third module at the top level, so when the first two modules go looking for it in ./node_modules it doesn't exist.

As far as I know there's not currently away around this other than bundling. Is there any plan for a unified syntax?